# Drop Down direction changes according to free space

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am just into programing and I need your help.

I have an issue with my drop down `sub-menu`-s. I have a simple drop down on my header, however it is located too close to window border in this case only(Depending on permissions).

So the `sub-menu` opens beyond window border to the right side and user doesn't see the content of it.

**I want it to detect if there is enough space to open on the right side. If yes, open on right. If not open on the left.** Could you please help me to solve this issue?

[image]

This is how it works when it has enough space. [image]

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="main-menu-list">
        <li class="header-dropdown-item">
            <span class="header-dropdown-item-title">Admin</span>
            <img src="../Layout/images//arrow-down.svg" alt="">
            <ul class="sub-menu-list">
                <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                    <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Users</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item">New
                                users</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item">Users
                                management</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Contacts List</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                    <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Security</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Roles</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Roles and
                                Permissions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Column Based
                                Security</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                    <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Notifications Management</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item"
                               >Email Notifications</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Sent Email
                                Notifications</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                    <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Source Data Analysis</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Automated
                                Error Logging</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                    <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Technical Services</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Dropdown Lists</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >Unconventional
                                Tags</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item"
                                >Tag Matching Duplicates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="header-sub-menu-item" >3 Digit Code
                                Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.sub-menu
        background-color: header-sub-menu-background-color;
        color: header-sub-menu-color;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        height: header-sub-menu-height;
        padding-right: page-side-padding;
        span
          margin: 10px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          cursor: pointer;
        ul
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            font-family: font-default-content;
            font-size: font-size-ssm;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 0;
            li
                & + li
                    margin-left: 30px;
            a
                cursor: pointer;
        ul
            & > li:hover
                & > a,
                & > span
                    color: header-menu-active-color;

                > .arrow-right:after
                        border-left-color: header-menu-active-color;

                > .sub-menu-list
                    shown()

                > .sub-menu-list-right
                    showImmediately()
            li

                .arrow-right
                    cursor: default;

                    &:after
                        pointer-events: none;
                        position: absolute;
                        content: "";
                        width: 0;
                        height: 0;
                        border-top: 3px solid transparent;
                        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
                        border-left: 3px solid gray-color-3;
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        right: 12px;
                        top: 0;
                        bottom: 0;
                        margin: auto;
                a:hover, span:hover
                    color: header-menu-active-color;

        .main-menu-list li
            position: relative;
            .sub-menu-list, .sub-menu-list-right
                hidden()
                display: inline-block;
                list-style: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: black-color-1;
                top: 31px;
                left: -15px;
                z-index: $main-menu-sub-menu-list-zindex;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                li
                    position: relative;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    :hover > .sub-menu-list-right
                        shown()
                a
                    width: 100%;
                    font-family: font-default-content;
                    font-size: 10px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    padding: 10px 32px 10px 15px;
                    display: inline-block;
                &:hover
                    color: header-menu-active-color;
                p:hover
                    color: header-menu-active-color;
            .sub-menu-list
                min-width: 100%;
                hideWithDelay()
            a
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                color: gray-color-3;
            .active
                color: header-menu-active-color;
            .sub-menu-list-right
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
            &:hover
                .sub-menu-list
                    shown()
                    &:hover
                        shown()
                        .sub-menu-list-right
                            &:hover
                                shown()
                span
                    background-color: black-color-1
        .main-menu-list
            li:first-child:nth-last-child(2)
            li:first-child:nth-last-child(3)
                .sub-menu-list-right
                    left: auto;
                    right: 100%;
```

And Pure JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        handleMenuItems();

        // functions:

        function handleMenuItems() {
            var menuEl = document.querySelector(".menu"),
                userLinksList = menuEl && menuEl.querySelector(".user-links"),
                recentlyItemListEl = menuEl && menuEl.querySelector(".recently-visited-item"),
                favoriteItemListEl = menuEl && menuEl.querySelector(".favorites-item");

            if (userLinksList) {
                userLinksList.addEventListener("mouseover", function (evt) {
                    var options = {
                        url: "/api/userlinks",
                        method: "GET",
                        successCallback: onloadUserLinks
                    };

                    function onloadUserLinks(result) {
                        if (!window.__RAPMD__) {
                            window.__RAPMD__ = {};
                        }

                        window.__RAPMD__.lastUserLinks = result;
                        createMenuList(result.RecentLinks, recentlyItemListEl, "No recently visited pages");
                        createMenuList(result.Favorites, favoriteItemListEl, "No favorite pages");
                    }

                    if (!window.__RAPMD__ || !window.__RAPMD__.lastUserLinks) {
                        ajax(options);
                    }
                });

                userLinksList.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (evt) {
                    if (!window.__RAPMD__) {
                        return;
                    }

                    window.__RAPMD__.lastUserLinks = null;
                });
            }
        }

        function createMenuList(items, menuItemEl, emptyListTitle) {
            if (!menuItemEl) {
                return;
            }

            var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

            (items.length ? items : [{ Title: emptyListTitle }]).forEach(function (item) {
                var li = document.createElement("li"),
                    a = document.createElement("a");

                if (item.Url) {
                    a.href = item.Url;
                } else {
                    a.classList.add("empty-link-item");
                }
                a.innerHTML = item.Title;
                li.appendChild(a);
                df.appendChild(li);
            });

            menuItemEl.textContent = "";
            menuItemEl.appendChild(df);
        }

        function ajax(options) {
            var url = options.url,
                method = options.method,
                successCallback = options.successCallback,
                failureCallback = options.failureCallback,
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open(method, url);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200 && successCallback) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    successCallback(response);
                } else if (failureCallback) {
                    failureCallback();
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy CSS way to solve this. The only option I can think about is to align it to the left if the space is not enough. You can use the `document.querySelector("#sub-menu").getBoundingClientRect()` function to get the position of the element.

```json
{
    "x": 1261.5,
    "y": -309,
    "width": 298,
    "height": 452,
    "top": -309,
    "right": 1559.5,
    "bottom": 143,
    "left": 1261.5
}
```

Then you can check if the sub-menu would overflow out of the page and assign a class that makes it align to the left instead of the right.

```
const subMenuBound = document.querySelector("#sub-menu").getBoundingClientRect();
const windowWidth = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientWidth;

const subMenuX = subMenuBound.x;
const subMenuWidth = subMenuBound.width;

if (subMenuBound.width + subMenuBound.x > windowWidth) {
    // assign a class to the sub-menu to
    // align to the left instead of right
} else {
    // remove the class
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I kept working on it as soon as received it. What I have done for now is, I assigned a class(where your comments were left) to align it left and to remove it.  `document.queryselector(this).classlist.add('left');` and of course `removeclass left`. But I cant understand where to put  `{ "x": 1261.5, .....` that you have mentioned above. Thank you.

Comment: Great that I could help. The JSON was just supposed to show you what is returned by the .getBoundingClientRect() function (so just complimentary info's). It was not supposed to be part of the actual code.